# Generate a random number which is far enough from another number

Tags: random

Let `x, range, d` be integers. We'd like to generate a number `y`, such that

- `1 <= y <= range`
- `abs(x-y) >= d`

One idea I came up with is to generate some smaller range and then make some adjustments to handle the numbers which too close to `x`. But that's really tedious.

Is there any better way to do it?

Comment: Would taking the distance you want `d` and then adding the random number to it be an option? Such that `d+y` will be random and always at the wanted distance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a Python function that you should be able to adapt to the language of your choice:

```
import random

def distantRand(a,b,x,d):
    #returns a random integer in range a ... b
    #which is greater than or equal to d units from x

    lb = max(a,x-d+1)
    ub = min(b,x+d-1)
    k = ub-lb+1 #number of numbers ruled out

    if b-k < a:
        return None
    else:
        y = random.randint(a,b-k)
        if y > x - d:
            y = y + k
        return y
```

For example, `distantRand(1,10,5,3)` should return a number in the range 1 to 10 which is at least units away from 5. This rules out 3,4,5,6,7 as return values, leaving 10-5 = 5 valid numbers. The function picks one such in the range 1 to 5. If the number chosen is >2, 5 is added to it to make it a number which is >7 (but still <= 10). For example:

```
>>> for i in range(20):
    print(distantRand(1,10,5,3))

1
1
1
8
2
9
10
8
1
10
10
2
8
10
8
8
8
2
1
2
```

Comment: `x-d` may be negative, for example `distantRand(1,10,2,4)`

Comment: @marmistrz Good point. I took more care in how I computed `k`.

Answer (score 1):

I have done it like this in Python.

```
import random

range=100
d=20
x=115

while(True): 
    y=random.randint(1,range)
    if abs(x-y)>=d:     
        print abs(x-y)
        print y
        break
```

And here it is as a def

```
import random

r=100
d=20
x=115

def yourandom (x,d,r):
    while(True):
        y=random.randint(1,r)
        if abs(x-y)>=d:
            print "abs(x-y)=",abs(x-y)
            print "y=",y
            break


yourandom(x,d,r)
```

Comment: This is perfectly reasonable for small `d` but becomes markedly inefficient for larger `d`. If `x = 500, d = 499, range = 1000` the loop can be expected to go hundreds of times. Still -- it is working idea so +1

Comment: I know but his post was a bit unclear to me. I assumed he just wanted a quick fix. There are a few more things to consider. working on it now ;)

Comment: And, if we have enough bad luck, the loop may run forever. And error checking is pretty hard

Comment: Sometimes a quick and dirty approach is perfectly reasonable.